# Fetching an object's parent id from the database (which is created by MVC through a virtual ICollection)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

My database is generated by EF-CodeFirst. I have 3 models, containing Boards, Threads and Posts. Instead of manually keeping track of all the parent_id values, I have created them with some ICollections, so that EF does this for me.

However, when I'm on a Threads/View/5 page, I'd like to be able to fetch its parent board Id, but I don't know how. The column does exist in the database though, as all EF does is create a Board_Id field and fill it when I'm creating the Thread and adding it to the database.Threads ICollection.

Here's my code:

```
// Board model, containing a title and a collection of threads
public class Board
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Thread> Threads { get; set; }
}

// Thread model, containing a title and a collection of posts
public class Thread
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I'm in the Threads/View action, how do I go about fetching the value from the column Board_Id?

```
// GET: Threads/View/5
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult View(int? id) {
    Thread thread = db.Threads.Find(id);

    // Fetch the parent board Id
    int boardId = ...;

    return View(thread);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a Board property in your Thread class. The property will be

```
public virtual Board Board {get; set;}
```

with that property you will be able to navigate from Thread to Board